# Jenkins. Изменить "Remote root directory" groovy-скриптом

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить значение "Remote root directory" в настройках ноды Jenkins с помощью Groovy-скрипта? Планирую изменить точку монтирования для большой группы нод, как-то это не правильно руками всё перебивать)

Comment: через `rest`. но менять этот конфиг - плохая идея на мой взгляд

Comment: возможно еще [тут][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780554/how-to-set-the-workspace-root-directory-on-jenkins-slaves] имеется ответ на твой вопрос

Comment: Похоже, что просто так этот параметр не изменить.

Comment: Похоже, что просто так этот параметр не изменить.В коде вот такая переменная: "protected final String remoteFS". Т.е. сделать можно только пересоздав объект. Я прав?

Comment: при установке можно задать этот пар-р. Вам не нужно залезть в код, In the Build job go to the "Advanced Project Options" section and click the Advanced button.  Set the "Use custom workspace" directory to: D:\wp

Comment: После изменения точки монтирования измениться и расположение slave.jar. В итоге нода не будет работать. Видимо, придётся руками прокликать (